# show ProgressDialog onActivityResult

Tags: android, webview, android-activity, progressdialog

I have two activities the first one load url(simple webview) and the second one get the id for url from listview then call back the first activity to load the url.
I'm use `onActivityResult()` method in the first activity to get the extra data(url id).
My problem is when I want to show the ProgressDialog in the first Activity in method `onActivityResult()` after choose item from ListView in second activity I got a ProgressDialog but it just shows for seconds (very quickly) then disappear before complete the load for url(WebView)

This is the code for the tow activities I hope help me.

```
public class LibActivity extends Activity {

private ImageButton btnCategoriesList;

public static final int BOOK_CATEGORY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

private WebView webView;

public ProgressDialog dialog;
private Handler handler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lib);

    handler = new Handler();
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading", "Please wait", true, false);

    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.categoryWebView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new CategoryItemWebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://maktabati.mobi/V3/store.php?catid=" + "91");

    btnCategoriesList = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_category_list);

    btnCategoriesList.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showBooksCategories();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * 
 */
protected void showBooksCategories() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BooksCategoriesActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, BOOK_CATEGORY_REQUEST_CODE);
}

/**
 * 
 * @author Jamil
 * 
 */
private class CategoryItemWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.contains("book")) {
            String bookId = url.substring(12);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BookDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("BOOK_ID", bookId);
            startActivity(intent);
            view.stopLoading();
        }
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == BOOK_CATEGORY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading", "Please wait", true);
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    webView.loadUrl("http://maktabati.mobi/V3/store.php?catid=" + data.getStringExtra("CATEGORY_ID"));
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }.start();

        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

the second activity

```
public class BooksCategoriesActivity extends Activity {

ItemsCategoriesAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<Category> lstCategory;
Handler handlerProgressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.books_categories_list);
    handlerProgressDialog = new Handler();
    CategoryHandler handler = new CategoryHandler();
    ParserCreater parserCreater = new ParserCreater(handler);
    parserCreater.parse("http://maktabati.mobi/V3/getCategories.php");
    lstCategory = handler.getLstCategory();
    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.categories_list);
    adapter = new ItemsCategoriesAdapter(lstCategory);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, final int position, long arg3) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LibActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("CATEGORY_ID", lstCategory.get(position).getId());
            BooksCategoriesActivity.this.setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please try what happens if you remove the following code from the onActivityResult function:

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
```

The `onPageFinished()` function should be called after `webView.loadUrl()`.

Comment: Thanks very much guys I did what u told me I didn't call the method loadUrl from a thread and I call the dialog.show in method onPageStarted and it works but I don't know if it is the right one.

Comment: also working for showing the dialog instead of dismissing it

Answer (score 0):

The method `loadUrl()` is not a blocking call, so you don't need to call it from a background thread.  If you want to capture the point at which the page is finished loading, you can set a `WebviewClient` object on your `WebView` to handle a series of callbacks in this regard.

Also, since that call does not block, it returns immediately and your `dismiss()` method is called almost as soon as `show()`, which is why you see it display only briefly.

HTH